# QueryDSL and SubQuery with Tuple condition

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, syntax, querydsl

I am trying to write a query in QueryDSL to fetch the oldest elements of a table grouped by their parentId.

The SQL equivalent should be:

```
SELECT a.* FROM child a
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT parentId, MAX(revision) FROM child GROUP BY parentId
    ) b
    ON ( 
        a.parentId = b.parentId AND a.revision = b.revision
    )
```

Now in QueryDSL I'm stuck with the syntax.

```
JPQLQuery<Tuple> subquery = JPAExpressions
                .select(child.parent, child.revision.max())
                .from(child)
                .groupBy(child.parent);

HibernateQuery<Child> query = new HibernateQuery<>(session);
query.from(child)
    .where(child.parent.eq(subquery.???).and(child.revision.eq(subquery.???))));
```

How do you write this query using a subquery ?

**The tables are looking like this :**

```
___parent___ (not used in this query, but exists)
parentId
P1       | *
P2       | *
P3       | *

___child___
parentId | revision
P1       | 1       | *
P1       | 2       | *
P1       | 3       | *
P2       | 2       | *
P2       | 3       | *
P3       | 1       | *

___result from child, the highest revision for each parentId___
P1       | 3       | *
P2       | 3       | *
P3       | 1       | *
```

**What I've tried so far :**

```
.where(JPAExpressions.select(child.parent,child.revision).eq(subquery));

-> org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected end of subtree
```

and many syntax errors ...

I use a dirty loop, for now, since I haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: Are there unique keys in the child table?

Comment: Yes, child.id and parent.parentId are the respective primary keys. (thanks a lot for taking the time to answer :) )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Expressions.list()` to specify more than one column for the in clause:

```
query.from(child).where(Expressions.list(child.parent, child.revision).in(subquery));
```

The alternative is to use `innerJoin()`, as in your original SQL.

Answer (score 3):

```
Expressions.list(ENTITY.year, ENTITY.week).in(//
                    Expressions.list(Expressions.constant(1029), Expressions.constant(1)),
                    Expressions.list(Expressions.constant(1030), Expressions.constant(1)),
                    Expressions.list(Expressions.constant(1031), Expressions.constant(1))
```

would be what you are looking for, but QueryDSL generates wrong SQL from it:

```
((p0_.year , p0_.week) in (1029 , 1 , (1030 , 1) , (1031 , 1)))
```

Comment: Your solution gave me a error in mysql, as `Operand should contain 2 column(s)`

Answer (score 1):

In JPA subqueries can appear only in the where part.

Here is my take on your query

```
select(child).from(child).where(child.revision.eq(
  select(child2.revision.max())
 .from(child2)
 .where(child2.parent.eq(child.parent))
 .groupBy(child2.parent))).fetch()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This query doesn't work when revision numbers are identical. Child.revision is not unique. There is no "child2" in my query, only a parent and its children. This is why I need to match the tuple, both values of parentId and revision in the Join On part of the query

Comment: Ok, is child revision unique in the scope of a parent? If not, then this will return indeed return multiple rows per parent.

Comment: I added an example of the data in the question.

Comment: Hi @TimoWestkämper, I have a similar query, however if I put eq() there, it gives this error when running the query: "could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not extract ResultSet". I think somehow the subquery is returning a resultset instead of a single result. And when I use in() the query can run, but the result is not as expected in some corner case.

Answer (score 1):

Building off of [JRA_TLL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3628421/jra-tll)'s answer - nested use of `Expressions.list()` is, per the maintainers of QueryDSL, [not supported](https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/discussions/2926). Choice quote:

> This is not really a bug, is just improper use of QueryDSL's internal `list` expressions for tuples.
>
> [...]
>
> The solution is quite simply: don't use the list expression for this. This use a `Template` expression.

Here's a version of [JRA_TLL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3628421/jra-tll)'s answer with the `Template` paradigm recommended by the maintainers, which does the right thing:

```java
public static SimpleExpression<Object> tuple(Expression<?>... args) {
    return Expressions.template(Object.class, "({0}, {1})", args);
}

// ...

Expressions.list(ENTITY.year, ENTITY.week).in(
    tuple(Expressions.constant(1029), Expressions.constant(1)),
    tuple(Expressions.constant(1030), Expressions.constant(1)),
    tuple(Expressions.constant(1031), Expressions.constant(1)));
```

This should generate the right SQL:

```
(p0_.year , p0_.week) in ((1029 , 1) , (1030 , 1) , (1031 , 1))
```

Note that this kind of query construction doesn't work for all kinds of databases; for instance, this is valid in PostgresSQL, but isn't valid in Microsoft SQL Server.