# QueryDsl Tuple in List<Tuple>

Tags: java, querydsl

Assume me having a table of cats with plenty of columns.
I am trying to do equivalent of this query in QueryDsl:

```sql
select * from cat where (cat.pattern, cat.breed) in (('calico', 'Siberian'), ('grey', 'Siamese'), ('tabby', 'Maine Coon'));
```

In Java I have this class for parametrizing my cats:

```java
class CatParameters {
    public String pattern;
    public String breed;
}
```

And this method (unfortunately incorrect) to fetch cats from database:

```java
public List<CatDto> getCatsByParameters(List<CatParameters> params) {
// something like this
QCat cat = QCat.cat;
return query.from(cat)
    .where(Expressions.list(cat.pattern, cat.breed).in(params))
    .list(ConstructorExpression.create(CatDto.class, cat.field1, cat.field2, cat.field3, .../* etc */))
}
```

This obviously leads to an error `"Cannot resolve method 'in(java.util.List<my.package.name.Cat>)'"`.

So how can I query some cats with (colX, colY) being in list of java objects with those properties?

UPD: I have found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34046050/querydsl-and-subquery-with-tuple-condition) on fairly similar topic with subquery instead of collection, yet I wonder if there is a way to do it with collection (or maybe somehow create List<Tuple> from List<CatProperties>).

Comment: Depending on the underlying query language this may be supported. Assuming you're using JPQL / HQL under JPA, this will unfortunately not work, as its not supported by the query language.

Comment: @Jan-Willem
Yes, JPQL under JPA. I have come up with a workaround that iterates over the collection and constructs JPQL expression as string by joining `String.format("(%s, %s)", pattern, breed)` and then uses it in Expressions.booleanTemplate(...). Thought there was a somewhat neater and tidier way to do this.

Comment: @Olegiwe how did you use Expression.booleanTemplate here? I've create the joined String but the following gives me the wrong query: .where(Expressions.booleanTemplate("({0}) in ({1})", Expressions.list(cat.pattern, cat.breed), joinedString))

Answer (score 1):

Per [the maintainers of QueryDSL](https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/discussions/2926), using either `CollectionExpression` or nested `Expression.list` isn't the right approach, and instead one needs to use `Template` expressions (as hinted at in the comments on this question). Here's how this might look:

```java
public List<CatDto> getCatsByParameters(List<CatParameters> params) {
    QCat cat = QCat.cat;
    return query.from(cat)
            .where(Expressions.list(cat.pattern, cat.breed).in(Expressions.list(
                    params.stream()
                            .map(catParam -> makeTuple(
                                Expressions.constant(catParam.pattern), Expressions.constant(catParam.breed)))
                            .toArray(new Expression[0])
            )))
            .list(ConstructorExpression.create(CatDto.class, cat.field1, cat.field2, cat.field3, .../* etc */))
}

private static SimpleExpression<Object> makeTuple(Expression<?>... args) {
    return Expressions.template(Object.class, "({0}, {1})", (Object[]) args);
}
```